# Change link inside jquery ui tab

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm trying to change the link text that is in a jquery tab but I'm getting empty value.

```
$.fn.addEditorTab = function(name, tabName, contents) {
            $('ul', this).append('<li title="' + name + '"><a href="#tab-' + name + '">' + tabName + '</a><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close" role="presentation"></li>');
            $(this).append("<div id='tab-" + name + "'><div id='editor-" + name + "' class='editor'></div></div>");
            $(this).tabs("refresh");

            var selectedTabTitle = $("a#fileTabs .ui-tabs-active").text();
            alert(selectedTabTitle); // empty string
}
```

I know I can get the .ui-tabs-active text as along it comes back but the a# I thought would get the anchor tag but looks like it doesn't. I'm not sure how to get the anchor tag I guess in the tab.

**[EDIT]**
I've been able to do the following but I don't like it:

```
var selectedTabTitle = $("#fileTabs .ui-tabs-active").text();
var selectedTabHtml = $("#fileTabs .ui-tabs-active").html();
$("#fileTabs .ui-tabs-active").html(selectedTabHtml.replace(">" + selectedTabTitle, ">*" + selectedTabTitle));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According your code. I see you are generating the tabs dynamic. 
This element `$("a#fileTabs .ui-tabs-active")` doesn't exist. 
None of your tabs active. 
You need to active your tab first. 
You can verify it by using this code to check the active tab exist

```
console.log($("a#fileTabs .ui-tabs-active").length)
```

**Updated**

Updated answer with requirement get/set/edit to change element's text of tab without changing it's child element

http://jsbin.com/kusujetaka/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Please assume a tab is already active because it is. This is fragmented code but the idea is what's important. With an active tab how to get/set the anchor text of it.

Comment: Hmm. it's weird . i still can get the text.. This is sample code i made http://jsbin.com/nekerefuvi/3/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Right, but I'm trying to change the link text. If I just set text("Test") it removes the link and span. I need to change the link text while keeping the link itself and the span.

Comment: Here you can do it like this : http://jsbin.com/kusujetaka/1/edit?html,js,output
I used jquery to change element's text without changing its child elements. 
You also can use javascript